# detecting height with flex column and overflow child content

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how I can make a child element (when the flex direction is set to 'column') occupy all the remaining space within its container. I want it to expand to the available space and trigger a scrollbar when its content exceeds that space.

I initially thought that using 'flex-grow: 1;' would do the trick, making the child element take up all the available space and adjusting its height accordingly. However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. When the child has overflowing content, its height also overflows.

To address this issue, I stumbled upon a solution:

> height: calc(100% - 40px);

While this works, it's not ideal when dealing with multiple child elements, as calculating this for each one becomes cumbersome.

I'm seeking advice on a more efficient way to achieve this. Thank you for any insights you can provide!

How i can resolve this? Ty for answers

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 300px;
max-height: 300px; /* Set a fixed height for the container */
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-grow {
    // height: calc(100% - 40px); // this is possible answer but what if i have multiply children?
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
  height: 100%; /* Take up 100% of the available height */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child flex-grow">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="child">Child 2</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you relied on `height: calc(100% - 40px);` instead of `height: 100%;` ? Why to extra -40px seemed to work for you?

Comment: Seems like you just forgot to use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `.flex-grow { min-height: 0; }` or `.flex-grow { overflow: hidden; }`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  min-height: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child flex-grow">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <div class="child">Child 2</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
      <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its work! Interesting. Why min-height: 0; help with this...?

Comment: See the good explanation in the answer that closed your question as a duplicate. Pay attention to the link [4.5. Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)